# Отправка Email-сообщений с любой почты на один адрес через форму на сайте

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Как настроить данную форму (почты Email , сообщений) на сайте, чтобы с заданного на сайте email-а отправлялось сообщение только на мою почту?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот Сервис Smtp

```
public class EmailService
{
    public void SendEmail(string fromEmail, string toEmail, string subject, string body)
    {
        MimeMessage message = new(fromEmail, toEmail)
        {
            Subject = subject, //тема сообщения
            Body = new TextPart("Plain")
            {
                Text = body
            }

        };//отправитель сообщения //адресат сообщения
        using var client = new SmtpClient();
        client.Connect("smtp.mail.ru", 465, true);
        client.Authenticate("", "");
        client.Send(message);
        client.Disconnect(true);
    }
}
```

Вот контроллер, в котором передаю вьюшку на сайт:

```
public class EmailController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SendEmail(Email emailService)
    {
        string content = "Количество Персон: " + emailService.Person;
        content += "Напишите сообщение молодоженам (не обязательно)" + emailService.Message;
        content += "Напишите email" + emailService.FromEmail;

        return View("SendEmail");
    }


}
```

Если конкретно задавать почту отправителя и получателя, то все работает, а как подставить во вьюшке почту отправителя, чтобы сообщение отправлялось на почту получателя?

Comment: Очевидно, что у вас в client.Authenticate нет данных для авторизации для ВАШЕЙ почты, С КОТОРОЙ будет отправлено сообщение. В вашем сервисе для почты, я думаю, не нужно указывать параметр "FromEmail", он должен быть получен извне (конфиги (appsettings.json, etc.), база и прочее), данные для авторизации, соответственно, от туда же.

Comment: Это я понимаю, вопрос был не в этом. Мне надо подставить почту(отправителя) , с которой будет отправлено сообщение на МОЮ почту(получателя). Так вот вопрос в том, как подставить fromEmail в форму заполнения на сайте?
Или это невозможно?

Comment: А как вы с чужого адреса отправите себе сообщение не имя данных для авторизации?

Comment: то есть нужно создать класс с авторизацией пользователей, а потом подставить в него параметры из сервиса?

Comment: Я просто ни разу не видел, чтобы от лица моей почты кто-то отправлял на своем сайте письма сам же себе, не находите это странным?) Вам нужно в любом случае отправлять письма ОТ СВОЕГО ЛИЦА, а не от лица пользователя, если только он вам не передаст свои данные для авторизации на его smtp сервере

Comment: нет, я создал форму на сайте, человек будет регистрироваться, а затем отправлять мне(на мою почту) со своей почты, с помощью этой формы, сообщения и тд

Comment: Еще раз говорю, что никто не сможет вам отправлять письма от своего лица, если не передаст вам свои данные, логика вашего приложения какая-то не правильная, имхо

Comment: Вы никогда не сталкивались , например, с каким-нибудь опросом, в форму которого вы заполняете свои данные и отправляете?

Comment: Да, я указываю туда СВОЮ почту, чтобы мне пришло НА НЕЕ письмо ОТ ВАШЕГО САЙТА, а не наоборот...